# I have a relational as well as star schema data model and I want to query for following results

Tags: sql, olap, cube

I have a relational as well as star schema data model and I want to query for following results.

1. Total publications for each journal for each year
2. Total publications of each author for each year
3. Total publications of each author for each journal for each year

Here is the data models
[Star Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYbF6.png)
[Relational Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbFpz.png)

Comment: If you can include what you have tried at this point, someone may be able to assist you better. From a quick look at your links, I would think that you can get the data in question from either of these schemas (not an expert in Star Schema, and only gave a quick look to the relational). If you have an example of something that you have tried, it will be much easier to assist you rather than straight doing the work from scratch.

Comment: It seems that you expect someone to write you six queries (three for each model) when you have made absolutely no effort yourself

Answer (score -1):

You have Dimention Table for publications And journal And Date And author
And also You must have One Fact that is consist date and author and journal and publications

after that you must Create Olap Database and at that you must Create Hirarchy for all dimentions  and at parts Measure you must 
Create Distinct Count for publications (Using Dimention author for Question 2)
Create Distinct Count for journal (Using Dimention publications And Date for Question 1)
Create Distinct Count for publications (Using Dimention author And journal And Date for Question 3)